# Capturing the IE windows using For Each window shell application

Tags: vba, excel

I need to capture the windows and need to navigate further, I am able to capture using the below code,

```
With objIE
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
    Set TBL = .document.getElementById("payersitecredential-table")
    Set PRV = TBL.getElementsByTagName("A"): PRV.Item(1).Click
    'once the above code runs, it opens up an another window and i need to set that window as object.
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"))
End With
For Each WINDW In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
    If WINDW.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then
        If InStr(WINDW.LocationURL, "newmmis") <> 0 Then
            Set objIE1 = WINDW
            Exit For
        ElseIf InStr(WINDW.LocationURL, "https://www.example.com") <> 0 Then
            Set ClsWindw = WINDW
            ClsWindw.Quit
            GoTo ThEnD
        End If
    End If
Next
With objIE1
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4 'this is the place i get error as object required
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
    .document.getElementById("InquireStatus").Click
End With
```

i have kept a wait time of 60 seconds for the URL to load, but sometimes the URL takes much time to load, at that time it is unable to set the object, could you guys let me figure out this and give me a solution.

Comment: look at using internet controls, from VBA references, it's a lot cleaner, you can wait for the readystate to be complete and for ie not to be busy.

Comment: Thanks nathan for your reply, but what the problem is i click on a link in a website and it pops up an another window which takes time to load, i need to capture that window and set as object for further navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this in support of my comment

```
Sub ex()

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim wins As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

For Each ie In wins
    Debug.Print ie.Document.URL, ie.ReadyState, ie.Busy
Next ie

End Sub
```

EDIT

I would utilise the above, like so, this will find the IE based on URL and wait until it's ready and return, so use `set IE=GetMeReadyIE("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba")` for example.

```
Function GetMeReadyIE(strURL As String) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim wins As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

For Each ie In wins
    If ie.Document.URL = strURL Then
        While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Wend
        Set GetMeReadyIE = ie
        Exit For
    End If
Next ie

End Function
```

Comment: thanks again nathan, but since i am new to this concept, where do i need to  mention the URL in the above code. I tried as below, but i am getting an error as "object doesnt support this kind of property" **    For Each ie In wins
        Debug.Print ie.document.URL, "https:\\www.example.com\", ie.readyState, ie.Busy
    Next ie**

Comment: have you loaded the reference?

Comment: Yeah nathan, i enabled the reference microsoft office internet controls, html library

Comment: "Microsoft Internet Controls"  where is the error, what have you tried to fix????

Comment: Hi nathan i have updated the code with the error comments. I am actually able to find the window and able to set the IE as object but i need to mention wait time, but i dont want to mention the time, i want the for each loop to run and set the IE as object until it find the URL.